# Can I add attributes to an object property at runtime?

Tags: c#, serialization, attributes

For example I want to remove or change below property attributes or add a new one. Is it possible?

```
[XmlElement("bill_info")]
[XmlIgnore]
public BillInfo BillInfo
{
  get { return billInfo; }
  set { billInfo = value; }
}
```

Comment: Out of interest, why is it marked both XmlIgnore and XmlElement?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

(edit - I misread the original question)

You cannot add actual attributes (they are burned into the IL); however, with `XmlSerializer` you don't have to - you can supply additional attributes in the constructor to the `XmlSerializer`. You do, however, need to be a little careful to cache the `XmlSerializer` instance if you do this, as otherwise it will create an additional assembly per instance, which is a bit leaky. (it doesn't do this if you use the simple constructor that just takes a `Type`). Look at [`XmlAttributeOverrides`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides.aspx).

For an example:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
 public class Person
{
    static void Main()
    {
        XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        XmlAttributes attribs = new XmlAttributes();
        attribs.XmlIgnore = false;
        attribs.XmlElements.Add(new XmlElementAttribute("personName"));
        overrides.Add(typeof(Person), "Name", attribs);

        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person), overrides);
        Person person = new Person();
        person.Name = "Marc";
        ser.Serialize(Console.Out, person);
    }
    private string name;
    [XmlElement("name")]
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; } }
}
```

Note also; if the xml attributes were just illustrative, then there is a *second* way to add attributes for things related to data-binding, by using `TypeDescriptor.CreateProperty` and either `ICustomTypeDescriptor` or `TypeDescriptionProvider`. Much more complex than the xml case, I'm afraid - and doesn't work for all code - just code that uses the component-model.

Comment: Marc, where did you get the information that it will create an additional assembly per instance? It really does that, but I was not able to find that on the docs.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to add/remove attributes from a class at runtime.

It is possible however to update the way XML serialization works at runtime without needing to edit attributes.  See Marc's post.

**EDIT** Updated