# Which variable would pass serialization at runtime

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

Is there a way to tell in `serialization`, what variables will pass the serialization and which not before starting the serialization?

My intention is that if I have two instances of the class that should pass serialization, to one that will serialize some of the variables that I define it, and for another he will serialize other variables.

(I want to set the attributes at runtime)

I use `XmlSerializer`..

Comment: I think this may be what you are looking for...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602384/can-i-add-attributes-to-an-object-property-at-runtime

Comment: What do you mean by "pass serialization?"

Comment: @KennethK. Which variables pass serialization = Which variables will be in the XML file. There are attributes that define it.

Comment: If you mean which data from a class is output during serialization, then any `public` fields or properties are output--provided they are not prevented by using the `XmlIgnoreAttribute`.

Comment: @KennethK. So my question is how to prevent in some cases from a variable to be  output during serialization

Comment: Dynamically, or at compile time?

Comment: @KennethK. At runtime (this is not mentioned in the question?)

Comment: @aletrasg I tried it, it did not help, it does always ignore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is that when I tried the suggestion of **aletrasg**, I forgot the part: `overrides` in this line:

```
 XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person), overrides);
```

When I added that it worked.