# How to exclude class fields from serialization by XmlElement name?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

Say we have a class like:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace XmlEntities {
    [XmlRoot("Agent")]
    public class RootClass {
        private string element_description;

        [XmlElement("Name")]
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        }

        [XmlElement("Surname")]
        public string Surname{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

And we want to serialize into xml only `Name` XmlElement. How to limit that at serialization?

Comment: Use the XmlIgnore attribute. If you want to do it at runtime check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602384/can-i-add-attributes-to-an-object-property-at-runtime

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you encountered the `[XmlIgnore]` attribute?  Adding it to members of your class will exclude them from serialization.

So, for example, you can replace `[XmlElement("Surname")]` with `[XmlIgnore]`, and then your serialized agent will look like this:

```
<Agent>
    <Name>John Doe</Name>
</Agent>
```

Alternately, if all you really want is just `<Name>John Doe</Name>`, you could write a wrapper class:

```
[XmlRoot("Name")]
public class NameElement
{
    [XmlText]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

*** EDIT ***

While it's possible to generate such wrappers at runtime, it's difficult, inefficient, and not very practical.

To do so, I guess you could reflectively examine your object and find the properties you want (`root.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => /* your logic here */)`), and use System.Reflection.Emit to generate the appropriate class.  While possible, it's not reasonable - it'd be a huge amount of code relative to your actual logic, and you could easily destabilize the runtime and/or leak memory.

A better way to achieve the dynamicism you want is to forego `System.Xml.Serialization` and use `System.Xml.Linq`.  This would require you to write code that built up the xml yourself, but it's super easy:

```
public XElement ConvertToXml(RootClass root)
{
    return new XElement("Name", root.Name);
}
```

You can write an XElement to any stream using the `element.Save(Stream)` instance method on XElement.

Read more about [Linq to XML at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx)

Comment: Is it possible to add it at serialization stage? (there are cases when I need all elements  and at the same programm there are cases where I do not)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to ignore the element at runtime, at serialization, you can use XmlAttributeOverrides:

```
XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
XmlAttributes attribs = new XmlAttributes();
attribs.XmlIgnore = true;
attribs.XmlElements.Add(new XmlElementAttribute("Surname"));
overrides.Add(typeof(RootClass), "Surname", attribs);

XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RootClass), overrides);
RootClass agent = new RootClass();
agent.Name = "Marc";
agent.Surname = "Jobs";
ser.Serialize(Console.Out, agent);
```