# generate code for xml-serialization

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, code-generation

I want to create a class to be serialized. However I want the `Order`-attribute to be explicitely set on every member within my class. So I wrote this code:

```
public void Process(CodeNamespace code, XmlSchema schema)
{
    var types = code.Types.Cast<CodeTypeDeclaration>().Where(x => !x.IsEnum);
    foreach (var type in types) 
    {
        foreach(var member in type.Members.Cast<CodeTypeMember>().Select((x, i) => new { Item = x, Order = i }))
        {
            member.Item.CustomAttributes.Add(new CodeAttributeDeclaration("XmlElementAttribute", ???);
        }
    }
}
```

I don´t know how to set the named argument `Order` to a valid value. I already tried `new[] { Order = member.Order }` but apparently this doesn´t work at all.

So what I want is something that creates this code:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    [XmlElement("MyProp", Order = 0)]
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for [adding attributes to an object property at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/a/602404/3796048)

Comment: @MohitShrivastava Not really, I want the attributes added to the created class itself instead to the serializer using `XmlOverrides`. However as far as I understood from Marcs Post I can´t neither *add* nor *modify* any attributes on an *existing* class. However in my class the class does not exist so far, it´s generated automatically at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is quite simple. I compared the process with `XmlElement`-attributes that were automatically added and noticed, that the attributes name is not `XmlElementAttribute` but `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute`. Furthermore - as the `Order`-parameter is an argument of the `XmlElementAttribute`-constructor we have to add it as `CodeAttributeArgument`:

```
var attr = new CodeAttributeDeclaration("System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute");
attr.Arguments.Add(new CodeAttributeArgument("Order", new CodePrimitiveExpression(member.Order)));

member.Item.CustomAttributes.Add(attr);
```